# Images Change on Button Press Broken

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a whole page of images to change when I click a single button. Here is my current code. My issue right now is I can change one image just fine but when I add the code to change the second image it stops the first image from changing and also will not let the second image change back to its original image.

Here is my JavaScript

```
    //First image
var imageSources = ["origonal-image.jpg","2ndimage.jpg"]
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("change-image")[0];
    var index = 0;

      buttons.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (index === imageSources.length) {
          index = 0;
        }
            
        document.getElementById("imagechangingid").src = imageSources[index];
        index++;
    });

    //Second image
var imageSources1 = ["origonal-image.jpg","2ndimage.jpg"]
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("change-image")[0];
    var index = 0;
    
    buttons.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (index === imageSources1.length) {
        index = 0;
      }
         
     document.getElementById("imagechangingid2").src = imageSources1[index];
     index++;
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are overriding your first event listener when you write below code twice. one implementation (I am guessing the second one) will override the other

```
buttons.addEventListener('click', function() {}
```

if the same button click should change both images - you should handle it in same event handler.

```
    var imageSources = ["origonal-image.jpg","2ndimage.jpg"]
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("change-image")[0];
    var imageSources1 = ["origonal-image.jpg","2ndimage.jpg"]
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("change-image")[0];
    var index = 0;
    var indexOne = 0;
    
    buttons.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (index === imageSources1.length) {
        index = 0;
      }
         
       document.getElementById("imagechangingid2").src = imageSources1[index];
       index++;
       if (indexOne === imageSources.length) {
          indexOne = 0;
        }
            
        document.getElementById("imagechangingid").src = imageSources[indexOne];
        indexOne++;
 });
```